Anchor: How to validate Token Program in Account structs?
In my account struct:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct WithdrawToken<'info> {
  #[account(mut, token::mint = mint, token::authority = signer, 
     token::token_program = token_program)]
  pub to_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,
  pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
}

How can I validate the token_program via #[account(constraint = settings.token_program == token_program)]?
Do I need to validate token_program against attacks?
From Anchor library, token_program can be either TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, or TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID public key. but attackers may try to use a fake token_program...
How can I save token_program into my Settings account?
#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Settings {
  pub token_program: Interface<'_, TokenInterface>,
}

the above gives me error: the trait bound anchor_lang::prelude::Interface<'_, TokenInterface>: anchor_lang::Space is not satisfied

By defining Interface<'info, TokenInterface>, your program will automatically check that the provided token program is either SPL Token or SPL Token 2022: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/a0ddeb375e5835c0db00313d3eced21512de8f5d/spl/src/token_interface.rs#L14
If you still want to save the token program somewhere though, you'll just want to store a Pubkey in your account struct:
#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Settings {
  pub token_program: Pubkey,
}


then use constraint = settings.token_program == token_program ?

That's right, you'll need to specify it by hand somewhere

if your token_program can be 2 different programs, i'mnot sure you can check it with constaints.
But you can check it the function :
if ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info().key().to_string() != "Token..." && ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info().key().to_string() != "..." {
    return err!(ErrorCode::PublicKeyMismatch);
}


Effe2, could you clarify why "Token..." and "..." ?
